# How to Move over to Maps V2 from V1 when using MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

So before, we were able to do something like this:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmanager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class AddLocationMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    public static final String ADDRESS_RESULT = "address";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_location);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Along with the layout class:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_title"
        .../>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/task_address"
        .../>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/map_location_button"
        .../>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/map_location_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/use_this_location_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="AIza..............................." />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/use_this_location_button"
        .../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But now this won't work with V1 keys, so my question is how can I change this to make it work with V2 keys? I've read that I should use fragments but I'm new to android programming so I don't know how to code it, and still make my application work as intended.

Thanks!!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: Whenever I allow android studio to provide me with the a map activity it ends up taking 18 minutes for gradle to build when attempting to run the emulator, which is ridiculous. V2 was supposed to take "less coding" but that seems like a lot more code to me. This should have displayed a map in which you could move around, but because of the deprecated V1 keys, it no longer works. I'm just trying to set it up so it can work with V2 keys (I have the key, but haven't had any luck beyond grey tiles for a map).

Comment: "it ends up taking 18 minutes for gradle to build" -- there are some ways to incrementally improve Gradle performance, but in general, you need a better development computer (8GB RAM, SSD, etc.). "V2 was supposed to take "less coding"" -- I have no idea where you heard that. Maps V2 is far more flexible and capable than Maps V1, but I have never heard anyone describe it as being easier to set up.

Comment: That just goes to show how much of a noob I am when it comes to android programming. I miss understood the stuff I was reading about Maps V2 compared to Maps V1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now this won't work with V1 keys, so my question is how can I change this to make it work with V2 keys?

Throw away all that code and use [the Maps V2 SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start). Maps V1 cannot use Maps V2 keys.

> This should have displayed a map in which you could move around, but because of the deprecated V1 keys, it no longer works.

Maps V1 has been deprecated for a fairly long time. It's been nearly 4 years since you could even *get* Maps V1 keys, and Maps V1 had been considered deprecated for a while before that.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you, I managed to figure out how to implement maps v2 (well, for the most part).